# Getting the information of an email with RobotFramework

Tags: imap, robotframework

I am using Robot-framework with the selenium2library for testing some web-application. The script log in and send an activation URL to some email. I use the ImapLibrary to catch the mail and read it out but I get following error.

FAIL : LookupError: unknown encoding: text/html

Can somebody help me out.

Following is the script I use

```
*** Settings ***
Library    ImapLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Email Verification
    Open Mailbox    host=imap.domain.com    user=email@domain.com    password=secret
    ${LATEST} =    Wait For Email    sender=noreply@domain.com    timeout=300
    ${HTML} =    Open Link From Email    ${LATEST}
    Should Contain    ${HTML}    Your email address has been updated
    Close Mailbox

Multipart Email Verification
    Open Mailbox    host=imap.domain.com    user=email@domain.com    password=secret
    ${LATEST} =    Wait For Email    sender=noreply@domain.com    timeout=300
    ${parts} =    Walk Multipart Email    ${LATEST}
    :FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    ${parts}
    \\    Walk Multipart Email    ${LATEST}
    \\    ${content-type} =    Get Multipart Content Type
    \\    Continue For Loop If    '${content-type}' != 'text/html'
    \\    ${payload} =    Get Multipart Payload    decode=True
    \\    Should Contain    ${payload}    your email
    \\    ${HTML} =    Open Link From Email    ${LATEST}
    \\    Should Contain    ${HTML}    Your email
    Close Mailbox
```

Comment: Which keyword is giving you that error?

Comment: Also, is there a requirement that you do all this work in a robot-based keyword? This would be much easier to handle if you wrote a keyword in python. Any sort of looping or conditional logic is hard to do in robot.

Comment: The keyword "Open Link From Email" gives the error

Comment: Have you tried contacting the author of that keyword?

Comment: Not Yet, I will try to contact the author, thanks for the tip

Comment: Is it failing - and with the same error - in both tests? For the first one, it's semi-expected, as you're treating the email as a single part, plain text latin-1 encoded - and it is most probably multipart. In the second though, it should've check only the text/html part, properly decoded etc.

Comment: Yes it's failing for both, actually the second part was the one that gave me the error first.

Comment: I have found the solution to my problem, I just read the mail body then extract the mail from the body using regex. and open the link with the selenium2library. Thanks you all for the support

Answer (score 1):

At my company we use the [mailosaur library to test our email from our Robot Framework tests](https://mailosaur.com/docs/frameworks-and-tools/robot-framework/). We use different email addresses on every test run.

We also use Mailosaur for SMS testing but in a different test suite using Cypress

Answer (score 0):

This fork: https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-imaplibrary2/ solves the issue. If you haven't already found a solution, this should fix it :)